# Preg_replace replace dashes with spaces between tags

Tags: php, html

I have a HTML code and would like to replace only the dashes with spaces but only between specific tags.

```
function getTextBetweenTags($string, $tagname) {

 $pattern = "/<$tagname ?.*>(\d*)[-*](\d*)<\/$tagname>/";
 $replace = " ";
 $string = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $string);
}
```

CODE EXAMPLE:

```
<div class="xxx">
<a href="/start">start</a>

<a href="/start/world">World</a>

<a href="/start/world/fantastic-yyy-zz">Fantastic-yyy-zz</a>
  peter-hey
</div>
```

RESULT: Although 'peter hey' is without dashes it's more important the Tag's values.

```
<div class="xxx">
<a href="/start">start</a>

<a href="/start/world">World</a>

<a href="/start/world/fantastic-yyy-zz">Fantastic yyy zz</a>
  peter-hey
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You **DO NOT** need regular expressions for this task:

```
$contents = '<div class="xxx">
<a href="/start">start</a>

<a href="/start/world">World</a>

<a href="/start/world/fantastic-yyy-zz">Fantastic-yyy-zz</a>
  peter-hey
</div>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($contents);

$tagName = 'a';

$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName($tagName);

foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $newValue = str_replace('-', ' ', $tag->nodeValue);
    $tag->nodeValue = $newValue;
}

echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/rI6k8b

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I can't because I only get that piece of code as a $variable['breadcrumb'] so I can't use the 'getElementsByTagName'.

Comment: @user3720632: "I only get that piece of code as a `$variable['breadcrumb']`" --- what does it mean?

Comment: Sorry, the program that I'm using to create a web page uses this variable in a file (*.php), what I'm doing is to modify this variable before it shows up. I really don't know how to insert a function once the web is loaded.

Comment: @user3720632: sorry, I don't understand what you're talking about. I don't see any particular reason for regex to be allowed and DOM not.

Comment: When I try what you say I get this error: Fatal error: Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on a non-object in C:\...\template.php on line 206. Does it help?

Comment: @user3720632: It doesn't without the exact code that causes that. As you can see it runs for me, so you've made a mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

@zerkms thank you for your help and patience, tried almost exactly as you told but it shows a warning and doesn't make a change.

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Extra content at the end of the document in Entity
```

CODE:

```
function process(&$vars) {
  $theme = get_theme();

  if ($vars['elts']['#xxx'] == 'main') {

    $vars['bread'] = $theme->page['bread'];

    /*add code*/
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadXML($vars['bread']);

    $tagName = 'a';
    $tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName($tagName);

    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        $newValue = str_replace('-', ' ', $tag->nodeValue);
        $tag->nodeValue = $newValue;
    }

    echo $doc->saveHTML();
    /*end add code*/
  }
}
```

Comment: Provide the exact text you are loading

Comment: Is not what I load, I'm using Drupal and didn't found another solution for modyfing the breadcrumb. I found this function in a known file with the variable I'm interested on($vars['bread']) and just though to modify it before it goes back, no idea where. The variable that we modified has just the text that I put at the first post as CODE EXAMPLE, only the names of the inner variables were changed but not a single tag is different.

Comment: what you just said is not helpful. You have issues with the exact text. If you don't provide it - we won't be able to help you with it.

Comment: I'm sorry but it would be crazy to put here all the code. The web works without problems, only I wanted to 'clean' the breadcrumbs. Thank you again for your effort, I will try on developing some function.

Comment: as you wish. The error clearly states that there is something wrong with your html though.

Answer (score 0):

@zerkms, I give you the answer as valid as you really gave a correct answer. I'm also amazed to say that I found some interesting answers:

CODE TO FIND INFO

```
$tagname = 'a';
$pattern = "/<$tagname ?.*>(.*)\-+(.*)<\/$tagname>/";
$matches = "";

preg_match($pattern, $contents, $matches);
```

CODE TO CHANGE : As I only have a piece of code, I really don't need to check the tag is 'a'.

```
$pattern = "/>(.*)\-+(.*)\-+(.*)</";
$replace = ">$1 $2 $3<";

$res = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $contents);
```

//$contents is my string with the code.

Hope it really helps someone.